# How to auto increment a variable after a condition is true for a different variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, increment

I am trying to develop a mini browser infinite clicker idle game.

My problem is that i am trying to auto increment a variable every second by 1, only if a certain condition is true.

Here is the code i have:

```
    var income = 0;
    var a = 0;

    function buttonOne(){
    document.getElementById
    ("myElementName").innerHTML = " some text " + a++;
     }
```

Now the problem i get is that i want the variable income to auto increment only when variable a has a value more than 1.

I have tried the following:

```
    If( a >= 1 ){
    Window.setInterval(
    document.getElementById
   ("elementThatIChose").innerHTML = " some text " + 
     income++;
     },1000);
```

Now when i use the above code it does not do anything and it negativly affect my onclick function for buttonOne.

Does anyone know how to make variable income auto increment after variable a is a certain value. I have tried all other loops and nothing is working.

Comment: Put your `if` statement inside your `setInterval` callback function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to increment it *inside* the callback:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    if( a >= 1 ){
        document.getElementById("elementThatIChose").innerHTML = " some text " + (income++);
    }
},1000);
```

Comment: thanks a lot bro i was trying so many things at took just that little adjustment. O was so close to getting it lol thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use [prefix increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_()) scoped with parenthesis, like this

```
var income = 0;
var a = 0;

function buttonOne() {
    document.getElementById("myElementName").innerHTML = " some text " + (++a);
}

window.setInterval(function() {
    if (a > 0)
      document.getElementById("elementThatIChose").innerHTML = " some text " + (++income);
}, 1000)
```

However it's easier to read the code by incrementing the variables outside of the assignment expression like this

```
function buttonOne() {
    a++;
    document.getElementById("myElementName").innerHTML = " some text " + a;
}

window.setInterval(function() {
    if (a > 0) {
      income++;
      document.getElementById("elementThatIChose").innerHTML = " some text " + income;
  }
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Yet another great answer. Thanks guys i have adapted and evolved the code you gave. I now have 5 variables updating the variable income.